# Can defer recover prevent mutex Unlock?

Tags: go, mutex

I have the following simplified code. I want to achieve that the manager's TryHandle function is only executed when the mutex is not locked, otherwise skip the execution. TryHandle can be accessed from multiple go routines:

```
var (   
    mu          sync.Mutex
)

// can be accessed by multiple go routines
func (m *Manager) TryHandle(work *Work) {
    if mu.TryLock() {       
        defer mu.Unlock()
        defer func() {
            if r := recover(); r != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Recovered from panic. Error: %s\n", r)
                fmt.Println("stacktrace from panic: \n" + string(debug.Stack()))
            }
        }()
        m.HandleWork(work)  
    } else {
        fmt.Println("mutex is busy.")
    }
}
```

At first it seemed to work, the program was running for some hours quite well. TryHandle was accessed frequently up to 5-10 times per second, and a very few times the mutex was actually busy.

But this morning I saw in the logs that "mutex is busy" every time TryHandle was called, and one cpu was running at 100%.

Of course, the most obvious reason could be that one call to m.HandleWork() never returned and the mutex was never unlocked. Unfortunately the log buffer is not so big so I don't have the proof.

But apart from that, and since I am (almost!) sure m.HandleWork can not be the culprit, is it possible that there was a panic and my defer recover function somehow prevented the defer mu.Unlock()?

Or is it maybe a problem that I define mu standalone instead of making it a field on my managers struct?

Comment: Is `*Manager.HandleWork` expensive? Does `Work` have some kind of identity in the form of a `string`? Can a manager handle different `Work`s concurrently without locking? If so, consider using https://golang.org/x/sync/singleflight instead of guarding everything with a mutex.

Comment: Just stick a `panic()` in there to find out how it behaves. Also, perhaps an infinite sleep would cause the same issues.

Comment: The fact that you find you need `TryLock` at all may be a sign that your locking strategy has underlying issues that need to be investigated. The docs even go so far to state: _“… use of TryLock is often a sign of a deeper problem in a particular use of mutexes”_

Comment: Many thanks guys for your comments. HandleWork is expensive, yes. Work can not be handled concurrently without locking, no. Will look into singleflight anyway, thanks. 
Good idea regarding the panic() and sleep. 
@JimB I am aware of the docs, but my use case which I described above makes TryLock exactly the right thing to use, but maybe I oversee something.